# having trouble installing Kali Linux on GRUB

Tags: grub2, kali-linux

Does anyone know the specific steps on installing Kali Linux through the grub bootloader. I have what should be a kali linux bootable usb and I'm trying to install it on a Lenovo 64-bit intel laptop that already has Windows 7 and Ubuntu Linux installed on it. When I am in the OS selection menu and press c to get the grub command line, my commands are

```
grub > set root=(hd1,msdos1)
grub > linux (hd1,msdos1)/install/vmlinuz
grub > boot
```

The computer appears to try to boot into Kali linux and then just freezes up. Any idea on what else I need to do? Are there any other bootloaders that are easier to work with? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least four different ways you could get that USB media to boot. Let's first expand on the one you already tried. You are missing either some parameters for that kernel or an initrd file, possibly both. What exactly those extra parameters need to be depend on the distribution you want to boot, and I don't know the particular one, but as a start you can try:

```
grub > set root=(hd1,msdos1)
grub > linux (hd1,msdos1)/install/vmlinuz
grub > initrd (hd1,msdos1)/install/initrd
grub > boot
```

If that doesn't work it may be simpler to take a different approach and simply enable USB booting inside your BIOS configuration.

It is also possible to boot GRUB from GRUB, so from GRUB on your harddisk you can boot GRUB from the USB device. Try this command:

```
multiboot (hd1,msdos1)/install/grub/i386-pc/core.img
```

The exact path needed might be different, the above is my best guess based on the available information.

It is also possible to use a chainloader to boot the bootrecord from a different device just as if it had been loaded by the BIOS. This is often used to allow the boot menu on a live CD or PXE boot system to boot from local harddisk or to allow the boot menu on the harddisk to boot from floppy. It might be possible to use the same approach to boot a USB media from GRUB on an internal drive, but I am less certain about that because in that case both drives might expect to be assigned drive number 0x80 in the BIOS calls.